# Why can't I use "limit" with two unknowns?

Tags: limits, maple

[image]

Why does Maple 14 gives me back the whole function when I want to use "limit" with two unknown variables?

Comment: why the negatives?

Comment: Why the close votes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Giving back the function normally indicates it can't compute the limit (and doesn't know if it exists or not), maple 16 gives the same result (none) which i find suprising as the limit is obvious $1$.

When $x\to 0$ and $y\to 0$ we know that $x^2+y^2\to 0$ so it is the same as $w\to 0$ with $w=x^2+y^2$ so we have the limit 
$$\lim_{w\to 0}\frac{\sin(w)}{w}=1$$

We know that 
$$\sin(w)=w-\frac{w^3}{3!}+\frac{w^5}{5!}\mp \dots$$
So 
$$\lim_{w\to 0}\frac{\sin(w)}{w}=\lim_{w\to 0}\left(1-\frac{w^2}{3!}+\frac{w^4}{5!}\mp \dots\right)=1$$

Comment: wolfram alpha says it's 1 too but why? I think it should be _0_. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @gaskopeter added

Comment: sin(w)/w = 0/0 no? why 1?

Comment: @gaskopeter added, $0/0$ is not $0$ the limit can be anything, here it is 1

Comment: Thanks! one last question: "0/0" is an "indeterminacy case" that we need to further analyze?

Comment: yeah exactly, ah other trivial example is having the limit $x\to 0$ of $\frac{2x}{x}$ this one is obviosly not $1$, so thats why we need further analisation